# Is division considered the mathematical dual of multiplication?

Tags: peano-arithmetic, duality

I'm doing a bit of research for a tech presentation that touches on the subject of [mathematical duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28mathematics%29). (To be clear, my presentation is not on mathematics or duality, but mentions duality in passing.)

My question for the math folks is, **is it correct to say multiplication is the mathematical dual of division**? Or am I completely misunderstanding mathematical duality?

Wikipedia says,

> the divides and multiple-of relations on the integers

is considered an example of an "order reversing duality".

So in layman's terms, could a person characterize multiplication/division as an example of mathematical duality?

Comment: One thinks of multiplication as a 2-to-1 operation and then the dual (pictorially) would be an 1-to-2 operation. Division doesn't fit into this picture. Moreover, division has more to do with multiplicative inverses that duals.

Comment: they are just words and "inverse" is better, more accurate.

Comment: (1) This is not an appropriate forum for this question. Try math stackexchange instead. (2) I really don't care to be addressed as "math geek", no matter how light-heartedly it's meant. This is a professional forum. If you were consulting a medical doctor online on a professional matter, would you address him or her as "medicine geek"? No? I didn't think so. 

Comment: No offense meant. I'm a software geek, so I thought I'd be among similar kin. :-)

Comment: I wasn't aware of math stackexchange. Thank you.

Comment: I know you didn't mean to offend, but the point is that we don't know one another, and the presumption is a off-putting. No condescension intended, but please remember this is a professional forum. 

Comment: To be humble never hurt ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, when folks come into the professional forum of StackOverflow, we're addressed as geeks and it's a compliment. I had a mental picture in my head, perhaps planted there by XKCD, that math folks were similar kin, so I thought nothing of it. I now see this community is very much unlike what I had pictured, so I apologize for the apparent insult.

Comment: Don't apologize Jehuda-Gavriel ;) You have the right to ask questions, what could be science if we had to no freedom of questions and answers. Your question made me think about the notion of duality, so thx ! And good luck ! 

Comment: These two posets are "dual":  (1) The integers with the relation "x divides y"; (2) The integers with the relation "x is a multiple of y".  That is what the Wikipedia remark means.


Comment: I was <B>not</B> offended; I took your comment to be a light-hearted friendly one.  I think this is not so much a math-cs difference so much as it is the nature of this forum.  It is not uncommon for instance to see a more senior faculty member referred to as Dr. or Professor here whereas I think that would be more unusual at StackOverflow.  I personally prefer less formality in that regard because I think it creates a less intimidating learning environment, but I guess that's the purpose of Math StackExchange.

Comment: @Judah: your apology is somewhat nullified by making repeated reference to my "condescending" comment; apparently I offended you more than you me. For all those who have reacted: there is plenty of room for informality, relaxed interchange, and even jocularity on this forum, but as for labels to address such a heterogeneous crowd, how about something neutral and innocuous like "MO patrons" instead? 


Comment: @Todd: Based on judahgabriel's later comment, I think the root of the resentment came from the word "professional," which seemed to suggest a lack of awareness by the OP.  Combine that with downvotes and a feeling of admonishment, and this can lead to a sense of alienation by someone, especially a new user.  If you had omitted what may have sounded like teaching points and simply stated your personal preference for more neutral and innocuous words such as "MO patrons", I don't think any offense would have been taken.

Comment: To clarify, I am simply emphasizing my own personal preference that any criticism be tempered as much as possible so that it is least likely to embarrass or offend.  I don't think that it is unreasonable to ask that a person refrain from using a word with a potentially negative connotation, but IMHO, it seems that simply mentioning one's personal dislike for the word is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand duality. A better example is: planes and lines through the origin (in 3-dimensional space). To each plane you can assign the line perpendicular to it, and vice versa. This is more just a pairing of two kinds of objects, it has interesting properties. For example, a collection of lines are contained in one plane if and only if the corresponding perpendicular planes contain one line. Or, the angle between two lines is equal to the angle between the corresponding perpendicular planes. This is where things start to become interesting: certain statements about lines through the origin (in 3-dimensional space) can be reformulated as statements about planes through the origin (in 3-dimensional space). In mathematics this is very useful. It happens, for example, that switching back and forth between the two "worlds" in a duality gradually enhances our understanding in both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful (and non-condescending) response. 

Answer (score 0):

I think that non-technically, duality is pretty unrestricted (if the dual of A is B, then the dual of B is A).  But if you use it technically, it is important to say exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: sorry this wasn't supposed to be condescending

Comment: This wasn't condescending. Some of the comments to my question, however, were.